# Rails - Google analytics - update with poll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I'm developing a rails **[application](https://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com)** and I have created an introduction **[video](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo)** that is about 10 minutes long.

I want to somehow push updates (poll?) to Google Analytics when users are watching the video because otherwise they're not displayed as active visitors after 4 minutes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean user activity at Google Analytics real-time reports?

Comment: @buttersmai yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use Google Analytics events-it will send hits to Google Analytics and show, that user do not leave the page.
You can use setTimeOut or setInterval at JavaScrpt to send hits(for example, every 2 min), or you can even use Youtube API and link it with Google Analytics events.